# Can't add gifs due to something wrong in my script

Tags: php, gif, helper

Made an Image Upload script however I can't seem to adjust it to take gif images as well or any other besides Jpeg. Can someone please help me with this little problem I am having.

Index.php

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
    mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","fingerdawg", "");
    mysql_select_db("test");

        $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));

        $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);

        if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image" )
        {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `blob` VALUES ('','$imageName', '$imageData')");
            }
        else;
        {
        echo "Only images are allowed";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Showimages.php

```
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","fingerdawg", "");
mysql_select_db("test");

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blob` WHERE `id`='$id'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $imageData = $row["image"];
    }
    header("content-type: image/jpeg ");
    echo $imageData;
    }
else {
    echo "error!";

    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

one proble is your view scriot alwats says the image is `image/jpeg` even when it's not.
either add a column to the table to stpre that or guess the type from the file name.